# GWT:style different tabs with different colors in TabLayout Panel

Tags: gwt

I am trying to give different colors to each tab of my tab Layout panel in GWT2.5

Right now i have this tablayout (image attached), 
You can see that all tabs have the same color except the tab which has been selected,
What i want is , 1st tab should be of yellow color , 2nd tab red color  , 3rd tab green color ,all the time, either they have been selected or not ..

Please let me know if there's a solution for this

thanks

[image]

Comment: Junai,See weather it's help ful or not :http://blog.technowobble.com/2011/03/styling-individual-and-nested-tabs.html

Comment: And this :http://peterlairdtech.blogspot.in/2010/04/sample-code-for-gwt-tablayoutpanel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use add(Widget child, Widget tab) to provide your own implementation of tab and your own css for it.
Or you can use getTabWidget(int index) to add your css to current tab widget.